# Primary site file uploads failing, subdirectory subsites upload fine

Tags: multisite, directory, uploads

Pardon the cross-posting (also up at Wordpress.org):

We're tearing our hair out here. We have multisite configuration working, subdirectory style. File uploads work to the subsites, but the primary (blog 1) site doesn't see any upload traffic. We're running on Ubuntu so have the Debian style configuration layout.

/etc/wordpress/htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# viewing attached files
RewriteRule ^/wp-uploads/(.*)$ /srv/www/wp-uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]

# force HTTPS always
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:IS_HTTP} !1
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

/etc/wordpress/config-bclaconnect.ca.php:

```
$upload_path = "/srv/www/wp-uploads/bclaconnect.ca";
$upload_url_path = "http://bclaconnect.ca/wp-uploads";

# Support for WP Networks functionality
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'bclaconnect.ca' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

And finally, /etc/wordpress/wp-config.php:

```
define('ABSPATH', '/usr/share/wordpress/');
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

There is no trace of the uploads in log files anywhere on the system. What on earth is going on? Anyone?

Frantic, in Vancouver,
Erik

Comment: What do you mean by "upload traffic"? Can _you_ upload anything? If not — what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: As the title says, uploads to the primary site vanish. As I said in the text, there is no trace of the upload in any log file on the system that I have checked.  Uploading media to subsites works; uploading media to the primary site does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a setting error on my part.  In Network Admin > Sites > Settings for blog /, I had not updated the File uploads URL field.  One little variable ....